# not able to understand below Error message

Tags: angular, plugins, ionic4, npm-install, ionic-native

When i try to execute npm install am getting below error. Please let me know why this error coming , how to understand below error

```
npm ERR! While resolving: @ionic-native/android-permissions@5.36.0
npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/cdk@15.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"15.0.0" from @angular/material@15.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       peer @angular/material@"15.0.0" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@15.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
npm ERR!         @angular/material-moment-adapter@"15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"15.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/common@15.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@">=6.1.0" from @angular-slider/ngx-slider@2.0.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-slider/ngx-slider
npm ERR!       @angular-slider/ngx-slider@"2.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from @angular/cdk@15.0.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!       peer @angular/cdk@"15.0.0" from @angular/material@15.0.0
npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!         peer @angular/material@"15.0.0" from @angular/material-moment-adapter@15.0.0
npm ERR!         node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter
npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     6 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/core, @angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/android-permissions@5.36.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/android-permissions
npm ERR!   @ionic-native/android-permissions@"5.36.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@6.6.7
npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/android-permissions@5.36.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/android-permissions
npm ERR!     @ionic-native/android-permissions@"5.36.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here am using rxjs 7.4.0 only . but still it says error

Answer (score 3):

I think this error was already reported [here](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/issues/3691). The problem is that you are trying to use RxJS 7 but Ionic Native needs RxJS 5.5 or 6.5.

From the error message, looks like you're using `@ionic-native/core@5.36.0` and according to the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#5361-2021-10-01) this issue was fixed in `5.36.1`, so the easiest way to fix this would be to update your `package.json` file to use the `5.36.1` version of `ionic/native` / `awesome-cordova-plugins`.

Comment: but am not able to find 5.36.1. NPM website itself shows latest version as 5.36.0   https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/core

Comment: Here which one is upstream dependencies

Comment: please check my edited code. Here am using rxjs@7.4.0. But still error

Comment: Yeah, Ionic Native was moved to Awesome Cordova Plugins some time ago, so in order to install the `5.36.1` version you'd need to replace `ionic-native` by `awesome-cordova-plugins` (they are exactly the same, just with a different name). You can find more details about this **[here](https://ionic.io/blog/a-new-chapter-for-ionic-native)**

Comment: Yes it is working fine now after moved to awesome plugin and made all plugins into same version

Comment: @RajaSekaran Glad to hear that! If you don't mind, please accept this answer ([here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) so that other users with the same issue know that this could be useful. Thanks :)